Animated Movie about fairies protecting their forest from loggers/evil
It's an animated movie and i think it's Disney (but they having re-release it yet) where a guy is shrunk down by these fairies and he starts to fall in love with one of them (the main heroine). in one scene he carves a heart in the tree with his and her names in it however she get's angry at him and takes his hand and puts it on the tree asking if he could feel the Tree's pain because of what he did.
outside the forest there is this big logging machine operated by 2 men who i think they know the guy who was shrunk down. they cut down one particular tree that the fairies used to seal way some evil, after the three had been turn into planks this tar like goo secretes from it and moves around the place which is apparently the evil. it climbs to the top of the machine and put's it's mouth over the exhaust pipe and "drinks" the exhaust fumes commenting it's like "mother's milk" growing larger as if it gets stronger from pollution.
this evil then takes over the radio and posing as the men's boss redirect them to go to the fairies's home tree, when they get close the fairies and the shrunk guy fight back and stop the machine but then the evil takes over the machine starting it back up, growing insanely large and now looks like he's made from smoke, though i don't know what happens to it after that

Movie identification questions must contain sufficient detail to be answerable. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions. Identification questions without an accepted answer will be deleted after 14 days.

@CGCampbell This question has an accepted answer, so how exactly does it not contain sufficient detail to be answerable?!

@VedranŠego i only just accepted it because of the threat of deletion as i am trying to track down the movie to re-watch it (however answer seems to be correct).

i would like to voice my opposition of such a policy mentioned in the last sentence, this answer took 6 months to be answered. also by deleting an id request just because it has no accepted answer is harmful as then another user may end up posting a possible duplicate but is still in the right because the original was removed but also forces askers to accept an answer where there is the possibility the only answer is incorrect

from my understanding, a question with an up-voted answer still counts as being answered in Stack Exchange statistics. if you have an abundance of unanswered ID Request then possibly you need to set guidelines and down-vote questions which do not meet these guidelines so then the question is automatically deleted (unanswered down-voted questions are automatically removed after X days)

This was discussed in another question. I should not have close voted, I should have flagged for moderator attention. Close voting takes five votes, so it is unlikely to be closed, whether or not there is an accepted answer. Since I cannot abide by identify questions, I will simply stop using this particular SE and leave it to our resident experts, Walt and Napolean.

You're definitely thinking of FernGully: The Last Rainforest (1992):

The magical inhabitants of a rain-forest fight to save their home, which is threatened by logging and a polluting force of destruction called Hexxus.

Wikipedia better explains the main section of the plot:

A curious fairy girl named [...] Crysta heads to Mount Warning where she finds dead trees all marked with red aerosol paint crosses, which mark them for cutting. The source of the smoke is the exhaust from a huge tree leveler. She finds male humans, and accidentally shrinks one named Zak in trying to prevent him from being crushed by a tree.
Zak's superiors cut down an enchanted baobab tree [...], discovering too late that Hexxus has been released from the tree. Seeking revenge upon the fairies of FernGully for imprisoning him, Hexxus gains power by feeding on the pollution, specifically the energy and smoke produced by the leveler.

You can see the trailer of it on YouTube.

And on a poignant note for this week, the character of Batty was voiced by Robin Williams
